# Make divs specified height before slideToggle, fit to content after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple div's that contain a server name and when clicked upon using jquery slideToggle, they expand showing the accounts that have access to that server. As an example: http://jsfiddle.net/CTBw3/

However, unlike the example, my divs are not the same width and height untoggled, and are longer with the more text that is hidden in the div.
[image: preview of page]

I was wondering how it would be possible to set a fixed width and height for the divs to make them uniform before clicked on, and then to expand to the size of the shown content once clicked upon?

My code is the following:

**CSS**

```
.left {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #DEDEDE;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    line-height:1.7em;
    padding:0px 0px 50px 0px;
    background: #1bacfa;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1bacfa, #1bacfa);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1bacfa, #1bacfa);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1bacfa, #1bacfa);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1bacfa, #1bacfa);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1bacfa, #1bacfa);
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
    border: solid #fcfcfc 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.left:hover {
    background: #4bc4fc;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4bc4fc, #3fbffa);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4bc4fc, #3fbffa);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4bc4fc, #3fbffa);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4bc4fc, #3fbffa);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4bc4fc, #3fbffa);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="left">
    <h1 style="display: block;">ADAL459</h1>
    <span class="info" style="display: none;">
    <b>Account Name: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Application Name: </b>
    CPS
    <br>
    <b>Server Subtype: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Server Type: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <i onclick="wasClicked(0)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i>
    </span>
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <span class="info" style="display: none;">
    <b>Account Name: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Application Name: </b>
    CPS
    <br>
    <b>Server Subtype: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Server Type: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <i onclick="wasClicked(1)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i>
    </span>
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <span class="info" style="display: none;">
    <b>Account Name: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Application Name: </b>
    CPS
    <br>
    <b>Server Subtype: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Server Type: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <i onclick="wasClicked(2)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i>
    </span>
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <span class="info" style="display: none;">
    <b>Account Name: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Application Name: </b>
    CPS
    <br>
    <b>Server Subtype: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Server Type: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <i onclick="wasClicked(3)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i>
    </span>
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <span class="info" style="display: none;">
    <b>Account Name: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Application Name: </b>
    CPS
    <br>
    <b>Server Subtype: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Server Type: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <i onclick="wasClicked(4)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i>
    </span>
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <span class="info" style="display: none;">
    <b>Account Name: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Application Name: </b>
    CPS
    <br>
    <b>Server Subtype: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <b>Server Type: </b>
    null
    <br>
    <i onclick="wasClicked(5)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i>
    </span>
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    <br style="display: inline-block;">
    </div>
<div class="left">
    <h1>ADAL460</h1><span class="info" style="display: none;"><b>Account Name: </b>null<br><b>Application Name: </b>CPS<br><b>Server Subtype: </b>null<br><b>Server Type: </b>null<br><i onclick="wasClicked(6)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i></span>
    <br>
    <br><span class="info" style="display: none;"><b>Account Name: </b>null<br><b>Application Name: </b>CPS<br><b>Server Subtype: </b>null<br><b>Server Type: </b>null<br><i onclick="wasClicked(7)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i></span>
    <br>
    <br><span class="info" style="display: none;"><b>Account Name: </b>null<br><b>Application Name: </b>CPS<br><b>Server Subtype: </b>null<br><b>Server Type: </b>null<br><i onclick="wasClicked(8)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i></span>
    <br>
    <br><span class="info" style="display: none;"><b>Account Name: </b>null<br><b>Application Name: </b>CPS<br><b>Server Subtype: </b>null<br><b>Server Type: </b>null<br><i onclick="wasClicked(9)" style="color:#b6e4fd;">Click to choose</i></span>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".info").hide();

$(".left").click(function () {
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
```

Just as an fyi, this only thing the "wasClicked()" function does is bring up an alert box.

Answer (score -1):

JS code updated : (http://jsfiddle.net/CTBw3/1/)

However this is not very pretty as one of the boxes are very big ! The third box is wierd because you have a long HTML repeating content compared to the other boxes

```
var max =0;
$(".left").each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).height()) > max){
        max = parseInt($(this).height());
    }
});

$(".left").css("height",max+"px");
$(".info").hide();

$(".left").click(function () {
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; however, this wasn't really what I was looking for. The code you provided simply makes the initial div the size of the biggest div and does not actually expand the it to fit the content contained once clicked.